# ExecuteScalar not returning negative value from sql database

Tags: c#, sql

> Blockquote

I am expecting -1 as the result which is from the procedure but it is returning 0 as result. The procedure returns -1, on executing it on query analyzer

> Blockquote

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    int _return = default(int);
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", customerId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeOffset", timeOffset); 
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityId", entityId);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdsandValues", IdValues);
                        object _out = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        if (_out != null)
                        {
                            _return = (Int32)_out;
                        }
                        return _return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Did you place the breakpoint and see does the inner statement for `if` is executed. I believe the inner statement for `if `didn't execute, so `_return` will be 0 (as `default(int)`).

Comment: I see no SQL _language_ above. Perhaps the <sql-server> tag suits better.

Comment: As an aside, all those `catch`, `try`, `finally` blocks are noise and fluff. Throw them away; the `using` takes care of closing the connection and having unhandled exceptions travel up the call stack is what you get if nothing's caught.

Comment: *The procedure returns -1* - then that is the problem. If you want the return value of a procedure you execute it with a parameter on the command whose Direction is ReturnValue. If you want to use ExecuteScalar you run a `SELECT some_single_value` at the end of the procedure, not RETURN. If you want to retrieve the values of OUT parameters you declare them as parameters with Direction of Output. ExecuteNonQuery, as a method, has a return value that is tied to @@ROWCOUNT - you cannot use it to return values. You should not use RETURN to return data, only status codes. Use SELECT or OUT for data